# I want extract specific key, value form a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{'images': [{'id': 124,
   'file_name': '124.jpg',
   'height': 800,
   'width': 800,
   'license': 1},
  {'id': 125,
   'file_name': '125.jpg',
   'height': 800,
   'width': 800,
   'license': 1},
  {'id': 126,
   'file_name': '126.jpg',
   'height': 800,
   'width': 800,
   'license': 1},....
```

From this dictionary I just want to extract only "id" & "file_name" from whole dictionary
I tried a some ways but every time getting a empty list...
How to extract? please correct me!

```
temp = "id"

res = [val[temp] for key, val in data.items() if temp in val] 
  
# printing result  
print("The extracted values : " + str(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `id` and `file_name` value with `dict` wise value then use

```
res = [{d['id']:d['file_name']} for d in data['images']]
```

Similarly, you can make it into a `tuple` or `nested` list

```
res = [[d['id'],d['file_name']] for d in data['images']]

# Output
# [{124: '124.jpg'}, {125: '125.jpg'}, {126: '126.jpg'}]
# [[124, '124.jpg'], [125, '125.jpg'], [126, '126.jpg']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data = {'images': [{'id': 124,
   'file_name': '124.jpg',
   'height': 800,
   'width': 800,
   'license': 1},
  {'id': 125,
   'file_name': '125.jpg',
   'height': 800,
   'width': 800,
   'license': 1},
  {'id': 126,
   'file_name': '126.jpg',
   'height': 800,
   'width': 800,
   'license': 1}] }


files = { v['id']: v['file_name'] for v in data['images'] } 
print( files )
```